Are there any universal ways for a character to access elements other than their Vision's element?
I thought the Dragonspine Series' Weapons' Frost Burial would be a way to get Cryo without needing to devote a party slot to it, but no such luck, since the summoned icicle is Physical.
Is there any weapon, (or artifact (set)) that can give me an attack element that's not the active party member's Vision's?
